# How do I get rid of noise using temporal denoising?

Tags: rendering, animation, denoise

I have to render an animation in Blender, but when I rendered out the animation its all noisy and jittery.

I played around with both the samples and and noise threshold but still gets noise in my animation. I found something call temporal denoising on SouthernShotty yt channel, which include exporting in Openexr multilayer file format.Here's the tutorial I followed if your'er interested:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NsR0UybO-PY&list=WL&index=3&t=240s

I tried it out but still get noise in my render and the footage is overexposed. I don't know what to do can someone help me out.

The first gif is my render without temporal denoising and the second is using temporal denoising.
[image]
[image]

Here's the animations test and the blender files.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/174pr0sP0kc93EZTKtJvFEfdHuok7dmgS?usp=sharing

Comment: To be honest, I don't think anyone here is going to download a blend file which is around 850Meg in size! I can't really see any obvious problem with your test videos.

Comment: I know its a big file. If you notice on the wall with the plant the shadows keeps moving around.

Comment: How about adding a screenshot first?

Comment: Where do you mean?

Comment: In your question, you can add images or gifs. Edit: ah sry, i see you have uploaded a video.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Sorry for not being clear before, it's my first time posting online looking for help. I've added some gifs for you to get a better understanding.

Comment: the problem with GIFs is that they are noisy due to a size limit of color palette (max 256 colors). One trick to get around that is to convert your animation to grayscale before converting it to a GIF. Also disable transparency of the GIF.